# zabbix 5.4 Scheduled reports sending 404 error in PDF

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I've upgraded my zabbix to the latest version and i want to use Scheduled reports and after setting it up i get `Report was successfully sent to:` .But when i open the pdf file i get this :
[image]

and Log from zabbix_web_service.log

> 2021/05/25 12:07:42.592618 writing response for report request from
> 127.0.0.1:37234
>
> 2021/05/26 09:53:39.584874 received report request from
> 127.0.0.1:60450
>
> 2021/05/26 09:53:41.968368 writing response for report request from
> 127.0.0.1:60450
>
> 2021/05/26 09:59:44.456751 received report request from
> 127.0.0.1:33032
>
> 2021/05/26 09:59:46.289439 writing response for report request from
> 127.0.0.1:33032

I don't where the problem lays and i can't find answers since it's a recent version so if anyone is familiar please help

Answer (score 1):

Check which Frontend URL you have specified in the settings. It should be the same one that you use to login to zabbix.